# cycles render does not use correct texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

for some reason, my cycles render uses an old texture.

This is in shading view (what I expect):
[image]

Here is the cycles render view (what I finally get):
[image]

Also in the layout view it looks much more smudgy than in shading view (but it appears to use the correct texture):
[image]

My best guess is that something is not applied properly?

Comment: Check that the subdivision surface modifier has the same value in viewport and render

Comment: the donut does not have a subdiv modifier. it has been applied to the model earlier in the tutorial. The details are coming from a bumpmap and shader. in viewport and render they are almost totally gone / smudgy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That looks a lot like a lighting issue.  It looks like your render view has most of the light coming from directly behind the camera, and too much of it, both giving the image a flat appearance, and washing out the 'shadows' from the bump map.  I'd try toning down the scene lighting and generating more from the left or right side of the donut.  Shadows need side lighting to stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the texture needs to be saved separately in texture paint view. EEVEE takes the updated texture from the memory. Cycles takes the saved texture file.

Following the suggestion of Marty Fouts, the light was adjusted to come more from the side.

Even with the light set to 0, the scene was too bright. The World itself is emitting light from the HDR environment. It has to be tuned down in the world *Properties > Surface > Strength*:

[image]

[image]